# sql split string to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008

```
declare @sqlstr varchar(max);
select @sqlstr = 'a,b,c,d,e,f';
```

I want use a sql statement to one row with six columns in sql server2008.

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Are you just looking to split a string with 5 commas or is it actually more complicated?

Comment: (T-)SQL wasn't really designed with string processing in mind. So there is no "easy" way to do this other than work with Substring() and Charindex() to parse the string into individual variables. If possible, try to do the parsing before you get the value(s) into T-SQL.

Answer (score 4):

If you can declare it as `nvarchar(MAX)` instead of `varchar(max)` you could try turning it into dynamic sql. For Example:

```
declare @sqlstr nvarchar(max); 
--Select the initial values
select @sqlstr = 'a,b,c,d,e,f';
--Replace the comma so the string becomes a','b','c','d','e','f
select @sqlstr = REPLACE(@sqlstr, ',', ''',''')
--Add select to the beginning and add leading and trailing ' around the select values
select @sqlstr = 'Select ''' + @sqlstr + ''''
--execute the dynamic sql of select 'a','b','c','d','e','f'
exec sp_executesql @sqlstr
```

could also be abreviated slightly

```
declare @sqlstr nvarchar(max); 
--Select the initial values
select @sqlstr = 'a,b,c,d,e,f';
--Build the sql statement
select @sqlstr = 'Select ''' + REPLACE(@sqlstr, ',', ''',''') + ''''
--execute the dynamic sql of select 'a','b','c','d','e','f'
exec sp_executesql @sqlstr
```

Or if you're tied into `VARCHAR(MAX)`

```
DECLARE @sqlstr VARCHAR(MAX)
--Select the initial values
SELECT @sqlstr = 'a,b,c,d,e,f';
--Build the sql statement
DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Select ''' + REPLACE(@sqlstr, ',', ''',''') + ''''
--execute the dynamic sql of select 'a','b','c','d','e','f'
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
```

See the [Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5156/0) example

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare @str varchar(10)='a,b,c,d,e,f'

;WITH cte AS (
         SELECT CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(@str,',','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[1]').value('.','varchar(max)') col1,
                CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(@str,',','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[2]').value('.','varchar(max)') col2,
                CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(@str,',','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[3]').value('.','varchar(max)') col3,
                CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(@str,',','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[4]').value('.','varchar(max)') col4,
                CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(@str,',','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[5]').value('.','varchar(max)') col5,
                CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(@str,',','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[6]').value('.','varchar(max)') col6


)
SELECT   
        CASE WHEN col1 = '' THEN NULL ELSE col1 END col1,
        CASE WHEN col2 = '' THEN NULL ELSE col2 END col2,
        CASE WHEN col3 = '' THEN NULL ELSE col3 END col3,
        CASE WHEN col4 = '' THEN NULL ELSE col4 END col4,
        CASE WHEN col5 = '' THEN NULL ELSE col5 END col5,
        CASE WHEN col6 = '' THEN NULL ELSE col6 END col6
FROM    cte
```

Answer (score 0):

My variant with use CTE and PIVOT:

```
declare @sqlstr varchar(max);
select @sqlstr = 'a,b,c,d,e,f';
WITH cte AS 
 (
  SELECT 1 as pos, REPLACE(@sqlstr, ',', '') as sqlstr
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pos + 1 as pos, sqlstr
  FROM cte WHERE pos + 0 < LEN(sqlstr)
  )
SELECT *
FROM 
 (
  SELECT pos, SUBSTRING(sqlstr, pos, 1) AS sqlstr
  FROM cte
 ) x
PIVOT
(
 MAX(sqlstr)
 FOR pos IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) p
```

Variant with Dynamic PIVOT:

```
declare @sqlstr varchar(max);
select @sqlstr = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,t'; 
DECLARE @cols AS nvarchar(max),
        @query AS nvarchar(max)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#sqlstrTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#sqlstrTable
CREATE TABLE dbo.#sqlstrTable (pos int, sqlstr nvarchar(max))

;WITH cte AS 
 (
  SELECT 1 as pos, REPLACE(@sqlstr, ',', '') as sqlstr
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pos + 1 as pos, sqlstr
  FROM cte WHERE pos + 0 < LEN(sqlstr)
  )
INSERT dbo.#sqlstrTable
SELECT * FROM cte

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(pos)
FROM dbo.#sqlstrTable FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = '
SELECT ' + @cols + '
FROM
 (
  SELECT pos, SUBSTRING(sqlstr, pos, 1) AS sqlstr
  FROM dbo.#sqlstrTable
  ) x
PIVOT
 (
  MAX(sqlstr)
  FOR pos IN (' + @cols + ')
  ) p'

EXECUTE(@query)
```